# Write & Apply Python Function with Grouped Pandas Data

Tags: pandas, function, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have data that is grouped by a column 'plant_name' and I need to write & apply a function to test for a trend on one of the columns, i.e., named "10%" or '90%' for example.

My data looks like this -

```
    plant_name  year   count  mean   std   min   10%   50%    90%    max
0    ARIZONA I  2005  8760.0  8.25  2.21  1.08  5.55  8.19  11.09  15.71
1    ARIZONA I  2006  8760.0  7.87  2.33  0.15  4.84  7.82  10.74  16.75
2    ARIZONA I  2007  8760.0  8.31  2.25  0.03  5.52  8.27  11.23  16.64
3    ARIZONA I  2008  8784.0  7.67  2.46  0.21  4.22  7.72  10.78  15.73
4    ARIZONA I  2009  8760.0  6.92  2.33  0.23  3.79  6.95   9.96  14.64
5    ARIZONA I  2010  8760.0  8.07  2.21  0.68  5.51  7.85  11.14  17.31
6    ARIZONA I  2011  8760.0  7.54  2.38  0.33  4.44  7.45  10.54  17.77
7    ARIZONA I  2012  8784.0  8.61  1.92  0.33  6.37  8.48  11.07  15.84
8    ARIZONA I  2015  8760.0  8.21  2.13  0.60  5.58  8.24  10.88  16.74
9    ARIZONA I  2016  8784.0  8.39  2.27  0.46  5.55  8.32  11.34  16.09
10   ARIZONA I  2017  8760.0  8.32  2.11  0.85  5.70  8.25  11.12  17.96
11   ARIZONA I  2018  8760.0  7.94  2.28  0.07  5.17  7.72  11.04  16.31
12   ARIZONA I  2019  8760.0  7.71  2.49  0.38  4.28  7.75  10.87  15.79
13   ARIZONA I  2020  8784.0  7.57  2.43  0.50  4.36  7.47  10.78  15.69
14   CAETITE I  2005  8760.0  8.11  3.15  0.45  3.76  8.38  12.08  18.89
15   CAETITE I  2006  8760.0  7.70  3.21  0.05  3.50  7.66  12.05  19.08
16   CAETITE I  2007  8760.0  8.64  3.18  0.01  4.05  8.83  12.63  18.57
17   CAETITE I  2008  8784.0  7.87  3.09  0.28  3.75  7.80  11.92  18.54
18   CAETITE I  2009  8760.0  7.31  3.02  0.17  3.46  7.21  11.40  19.46
19   CAETITE I  2010  8760.0  8.00  3.24  0.34  3.63  8.03  12.29  17.27
```

I'm using this function from here -

```
import pymannkendall as mk
```

and you apply the function like this:

```
mk.original_test(dataframe)
```

I need the final dataframe to look like this which is the result of the series columns returned by the function (mk.original_test):

trend, h, p, z, Tau, s, var_s, slope, intercept = mk.original_test(data)

```
   plant_name trend      h      p      z      Tau  s  var_s slope intercept
0  ARIZONA I  no trend   False  0.416  0.812  xxx  x  x     x     x
1  CAETITE I  increasing True   0.002  3.6    xxx  x  x     x     x
```

I just am not sure how to use groupby to group by plant_name column and then apply the mk function by plant_name to either of the columns in the data shown. Thank you,

Comment: It seems `mk.original_test` returns a Series, so there would be 1 Series per column per group. How would the output dataframe be structured?

Comment: thanks - ive added what the final df should look like. The "x" values should have data in there but I'm not sure of the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given `column`, you can run the test in a [**`GroupBy.apply()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) and return the `result` as a `Series` indexed by `result._fields`:

```py
def mktest(x):
    result = mk.original_test(x)
    return pd.Series(result, index=result._fields)

column = '10%'
df.groupby('plant_name', as_index=False)[column].apply(mktest)
```

| plant_name | trend | h | p | z | Tau | s | var_s | slope | intercept |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ARIZONA I | no trend | False | 0.956276 | -0.054827 | -0.021978 | -2.0 | 332.666667 | -0.003333 | 5.361667 |
| CAETITE I | no trend | False | 0.452370 | -0.751469 | -0.333333 | -5.0 | 28.333333 | -0.026000 | 3.755000 |

Comment: yes, the solution is perfect - i just changed the index=True and reset_index() at the end. Thank you!